# Getting authentication error with HapiJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, hapi.js

I have created this simple plugin:

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import Joi from 'joi';

import DynamoDBClient from '../lib/DynamoDBClient';

exports.register = (server, options, next) => {
  server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', {
    validateFunc: (request, email, password, callback) => {
      DynamoDBClient.findUserByEmail(email)
        .then(user => {
          if (!user) {
            return callback(null, false);
          }

          bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isValid) => {
            return callback(err, isValid, { id: user.id });
          });
        });
    }
  });

  server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/api/login',
    config: {
      auth: 'simple',
      validate: {
        payload: {
          email: Joi.string().required(),
          password: Joi.string().required()
        }
      }
    },
    handler: (request, reply) => reply(request.auth.credentials.id)
  });

  next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
  name: 'login',
};
```

and loaded the manifest here:

```
import Glue from 'glue';

const manifest = {
  server: {},
  connections: [
    {
      port: process.env.PORT || 3001,
      labels: ['api']
    }
  ], 
  plugins: {
    'hapi-auth-basic': {}, 
    './api/signup': {},
    './api/login': {},
    './api/products': {},
  }
};

const options = {
  relativeTo: __dirname
};

Glue.compose(manifest, options, (err, server) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  server.start(() => console.log(`Listening to ${server.info.uri}`));
});
```

but I get this error

```
{
  "statusCode": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Missing authentication"
}
```

when I try to login passing a POST request with email and password as body params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your `/api/login` route should not be protected by an authentication scheme otherwise, you would have to be authenticated to authenticate. Chicken and egg problem...  All your other routes should be.

In other words, the login (and like logout?) routes should not be secured.

Comment: Make sense but if I don't protect that source which source should I protect?removing auth from there disable the authentication and the credentials object is null

Comment: I think you should protect the rest of your API.  I have never written my own strategy: mostly I used hapi-auth-cookie, with my own validation function.  There is a recent tutorial here https://medium.com/@poeticninja/authentication-and-authorization-with-hapi-5529b5ecc8ec that might help you.  In short, if you want to do your own, I think you need to setup a session somehow when authentication is done in /api/login then check that session in your other routes.